# Raspberry Pi Zero W Alexa Microphone Not detecting, but speaker works

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, pi-zero-w, alsa

So I have looked online and I even got different mics and adapters to get this working, but it still doesn't work. I was able to successfully setup my Alexa Pi on the RPi Zero W, because when I boot up the Pi there is an Alexa voice that says "Hello!" But when I say "Alexa" into the microphone it doesn't detect my voice commands. I know my microphone works and records fine because I tested it in Audacity on Windows 10.

I have edited asound.conf, alsa.conf
asoundrc and alsa-base.conf are empty

asound.conf

`defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.timer.card 1
pcm.!default {
    type hwcard 1
}
ctl.!default {
    type hwcard 1
}`

in `alsa.conf` I set `defaults.pcm.card 1` and `defaults.ctl.card 1`

I have opened `alsamixer` and adjusted the mic volume to various levels. But it still doesn't work. I have also attached a picture of my setup.

[image: Made in MS Paint]

Please let me know if you need more info and thank you in advance for helping out! A little project for my robotics team.

Comment: so, using the exact same setup, including the USB sound card, works in windows 10?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, this will work to record audio and output via speaker with the usb sound card. But I am having problem with the raspberry pi. I know the sound card isn't the issue because the speaker works. Just not the microphone.